# Laravel 5.2- Passing data to email view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to sent some user details through mail using laravel Mail. 
But while  I click sent mail button, it's saying following error.

> ErrorException in f007458b7fd9880a4f1d9bd9b684d2f236a70b32.php line 8:
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-roles\resources\views\mail.blade.php)

Here is the controller:

```
 public function sendEmail($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        Mail::send('mail', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
              $m->from('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx');

            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Thanks!');
        });
    }
```

here is the route:

```
Route::get('/sendMail/{id}',[
        'uses' =>'AppController@sendEmail',
        'as' =>'sendMail',
        'middleware'=>'roles',
        'roles'=>['Admin']
        ]);
```

Here is the mail.blade.php file:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Dear,
            Thanks for registering for the course.
            Login Details:
            @foreach($user as $row)
            UserName: {{$row->email}}
            Password: {{$row->phone}}
            @endforeach
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the mail sender button in view page:

```
@foreach($user as $row)
<a href="{{route('sendMail',$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Complete</a> 
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The route you are trying to access does not exists. It most likely has nothing to do with your mail function.

Please check routes file or post it here and let us know which route you are accessing.

Comment: What url is in your browser

Comment: and does your code match the middleware? 
    'middleware'=>'roles',
        'roles'=>['Admin']

Comment: Yup, there is no conflict of middleware!

Comment: there is problem with my mail.blade.php file where i can't access my user info which i want to send their email.
how can i access with that mail controller?

Comment: Ah, I see you have posted a different error now. That one is easy. You're doing a foreach on the user. But it's just one instance of a user. So just remove the foreach.

Comment: And obviously reference the $user instead of the $row

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you used:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
```

Which should return a single user object!

That means in your view, you can't use foreach for that user. To access that user data, you can just write

```
Login Details:
UserName: {{$user->email}}
Password: {{$user->phone}}
```

That should work for you.